# How is a Green Lantern ring able to have its possessor fly and make objects at the same time?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

How is the ring able to perform more than one operation at a time? Has an operating manual ever appeared?

Comment: If you want comic specific answers please include the `[comics]` tag otherwise you're fine :)

Comment: Though I don't have comic sources to back it up, let me ask this.  Can you walk and chew gum at the same time?  Can you drive a car and listen to music at the same time?  The point is flying might take some effort when they first get the ring, but it sure seems like it would become a skill that you could employ without actively thinking about it.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the rings' ability to perform to feats at the same time, rather than the users'.

Comment: Yes thank you Möoz for clarifying the question!

Comment: i'm happy with the edit. Retracted close vote.

Comment: The same way your PC or phone can do multiple things at the same time - it has hardware and software that allows it.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it be able to do it? The only limitations on the rings I've ever heard are the old (now gone) "Won't work on yellow things", and the basic "it can do whatever the user has the willpower to make it do".

Comment: Dual core processor.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the skill and willpower of the wearer, it can do almost anything.

> The rings use pure energy supplied by a Power Battery, which in most cases takes the form of bright green light. This energy is the green light of willpower of the Emotional Electromagnetic Spectrum. A green lantern ring has the ability to affect and use fundamental forces of the known universe, including electromagnetic energies such as gravity, radiation, heat, light, and powerful blasts of concussive force. The ring can also create fields of force formed from an unknown energy that is bound by the users' will. The limitations of such use are the skill, knowledge and imagination of the user.
>   <sub>-[DC Wikia](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Ring)</sub>

Hence, it is possible to do any number of simultaneous actions, as long as the ring is powered and the user is skilled enough.